# checking for missing components in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, logic

This is kind of an odd scenario, but I am trying to see if there is a complete set of 8 'robot parts' in a table that holds them all. I should be able to figure out the syntax itself, but the logic (kind of) is what is screwing me up.

I need to figure out how to do it in oracle sql.

Here is the scenario:

I have gotten to the point where I will have 3 tables of data, one for robots, one for parts in storage, and one for parts for robots.

Tables:

```
Robots
 RobotID NUMBER PK
 RobotName VARCHAR
 Status VARCHAR (either ready, or needs parts)

Storage
 PartSerial NUMBER PK
 PartType NUMBER (1-8)

Assigned
 RbPartSerial NUMBER PK
 RobotID NUMBER FK
 PartType NUMBER
```

So a robot can have the status of ready, which will mean if you look in Assigned table you will see 8 parts with that RobotID, all with unique serials and they will have PartType 1-8 (one of each).

If a robot has a status of needs parts, in the Assigned table you will see 0-7 parts with that robots RobotID.

So what I am trying to accomplish is, to check if any robots needs parts (easy), find out what parts they need (moderate), and now check Storage if I have those parts, delete them from storage, then move them to Assigned, if the robot got all the parts it needed I change its status to ready (hard).

What I have so far (just written how i would explain it, hopefully it makes sense):

```
while (check if max(status) is 'needs parts' (or min, whatever returns needs parts))

  --runs until it finds a part missing
  counter = 1
  while(missing)
    if (parttype = counter && RobotID = current Robot) in Assigned
      counter++
    else
      missing = false

  check if PartType(counter) is in storage

  if it is then 
    delete from Storage, insert into Assigned with RobotID

  --checking to see if it has all parts
  for i 1-8
    check for robotID and i (in Assigned)
    if no
      toggle boolean to false

  --if the boolean is true that means it found all the parts
  if boolean = true
    status = 'ready'
```

But now how do I get this to only run until it can’t move any parts, I could have the initial while loop also stop if Storage is empty, but what if I need part type 3, but I have part type 2 in Storage, it will loop infinitely.

Also for all I know my logic could be completely wrong, also if you have a simpler solution please share. This is killing my brain.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do the following:

1) Create a table of part types, which can be referenced by the Storage and Assigned tables. This provides the benefit that, should robots suddenly start using 9 parts instead of 8 you just need to add the part type to the table.

```
CREATE TABLE part_types (
  PartType INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR2(256)
);
```

2) I think you want PL/SQL that basically does the following:

```
DECLARE
  lPart storage%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  --loop through all of the robots in need of parts
  FOR lRobot IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   robots
    WHERE  status = 'needs parts'
  )
  LOOP
    --loop through the part types still required by the robot
    FOR lPartType IN (
      select *
      FROM   part_types
      WHERE  PartType NOT IN(
        SELECT PartType
        FROM   assigned
        WHERE  robotID = lRobot.id
      )
    )
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        --get the first part in storage for the given part type and store this in the lPart variable
        SELECT PartSerial
        INTO lPart.PartSerial
        FROM (
          SELECT *
          FROM   storage
          WHERE  part_type = lPartType.PartType
        )
        WHERE rownum=1;

        --call your assign procedure which would handle the following things
        --a) assign the part to the robot
        --b) remove the part from storage
        assignPartToRobot(pRobotID => lRobot.id, pPartSerial => lPart.PartSerial);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
          --this is really bad practice, sorry
          NULL;
      END;
    END LOOP;

    --check if the robot has all of the parts and then move it to the ready status. Replace this with your logic.
    IF robotHasAllParts(pRobotID => lRobotID) THEN
      moveToReadyStatus(pRobotIT => lRobotID);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
end;
```

I haven't tested it extensively since I didn't have data, but it should work. Hopefully it helps you out.

Comment: As soon as I get a chance I will write this all up. And I don't even have to make a parttype table, I already have one so I can use the ID instead of saying 'joint set'